# Using 'a' or 'an' with quantities

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phrasing

I seem to have trouble deciding whether or not to use 'a' or 'an' when followed by quantities:

> Built **(a/an)** 120 lb. robot.

and

> Built **(a/an)** 18"x 18"x 18" robot.

In terms of pronunciation, the first case could go like:

> Built a one-hundred-and-twenty pound robot.

or, like:

> Built an a-hundred-and-twenty pound robot.

Which would it be?

Comment: It depends on how you pronounce it.

Comment: … which is discussed (but not entirely resolved) in [How to pronounce number, say 1024, in programming world?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/159885/26083), [How to pronounce 100ish?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/186383/26083), [911: nine one one vs. nine eleven](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/216898/26083), and [Why numbers are sometimes pronounced as individual numbers?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/103953/26083)

Answer (score 1):

As usual with the indefinite articles **a** and **an**, it depends on the pronunciation of the next word.

I would read your example as: "***a*** hundred-and-twenty pound robot", but "***a*** one-hundred-and-twenty pound robot" would be equally valid.

On the other hand "***an a*** hundred-and-twenty pound robot" would be just wrong. You can't have "*an a*" together like that.

In your second example, because "eighteen" starts with a vowel sound, it would be "***an*** eighteen-inch by eighteen-inch by eighteen-inch robot".

Comment: So what would you use with "eight hundred and twenty-seven"?

Comment: @HotLicks you're absolutely right; as the only number which starts with a vowel, eight would need **an**. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: "Eight" starts with a vowel **sound**.

Comment: 'eleven' also starts with a vowel sound.

Comment: @Caesar Also "11" - *an eleven-inch gap*.

Comment: You are indeed right about eleven. I think that's covered by my answer because I have said that if a number starts with a vowel sound it will need **an**